# Query Not Working Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase that its structured as follows:

- "zipcodes"

  - 12345

    - 1

      - "city": "test"
      - "state": "XX"
  - 98765

    - 2

      - "city": "test2"
      - "state": "AA"
    - 3

      - "city": "test3"
      - "state": "BB"

I am trying to query my database by the user's zip code; however, when I try to view the snapshot that it found, it is null. Here is the code I currently have:

```
func firebaseSearch(zipCode: String) {

    let conditionRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("zipcodes")

    let query = conditionRef.queryEqualToValue(zipCode)

    query.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in

        print(snapshot.value)

        for child in snapshot.children {
            print(child)
        }

    })

}
```

When I run the code, I get this:

```
 (/zipcodes {
 ep = 12345;
 sp = 12345;
 })
 Optional(<null>)
```

My database has around 77k entries, so I was worried iterating through all entries and trying to find the child with my zipCode value would take a large amount of time, so I am trying to use the query feature to see if it's any quicker. I appreciate any help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need query for this, use `.child(zipCode)` instead of `.queryEqualToValue(zipCode)`. That will return the expected result.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly! Have a great day!